# Server 2003 blue screen all the time, even in rdc

Tags: windows-server-2003, bsod

I have a MSserver 2003, it is not working anymore.
What we have done is run a  regcleaner. After reboot we got the logon screen and after logon the screen stay blue and nothing happends even if i try logon via rdc. The service is running as it shut  (cmd and  Net service will show the state). I have tryed to run explorer in taskmgr but still nothing happends. My anvigation is running as service  and i can access it from workstations.
Is there som one there has a clue what to doo???

Jakob From Denmark

Comment: Does this happen for any user that logs into the server?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what you mean? It's not terribly clear :(

Answer (score 1):

Restore from backup, and get rid of that regcleaner.  You should *never* need those in any kind of normal operation.

Answer (score 1):

First check your event logs to see if something is generating issues (mmc.exe to get to the management console and just add the snap-in)

Check for any scripts stuck trying to run, kill unneeded processes in task manager.

You can try to do a recovery of your registry to just before the regcleaner ran.  Look in your last backup **before** the issue in the file location c:\Windows\system32\config.

The files without any extensions are the actual registry hives.  default, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE, system  rename the existing ones then copy these over from backup and reboot.

I agree with mh, you should never use a regcleaner on any machine.  They are snake oil.

Comment: +1 and in particular a server.  I want to scream everytime I see someone treating a server as if it was a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Last Known Good configuration, although it's a long shot as it sounds like the server has processed the logon but is showing nothing on the desktop. You can access the Last Known Good configuration option by pressing F8 during boot and selecting it from the boot options menu.